Why Image Zoom Container not showing while integrating react-image-magnify with swiper/react module?
I am trying to integrate react-image-magnify to my ecommerce repository which uses swiper/react as carousal. The integration worked but I am not able to see the zoom container while hovering over the image. Can someone help ?
Here´s the code for me product Thumbnail Component
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import { FreeMode, Thumbs } from "swiper";
import ReactImageMagnify from "react-image-magnify";
import Image from "next/image";
import { defaultImageLoader } from "../../../../common/utils";
import styles from "../../../../styles/components/Pages/ProductPage/ProductDetailsSection/ProductThumbsGallery.module.css";

const ProductThumbsGallery = ({ images }) => {
  const [thumbsSwiper, setThumbsSwiper] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className={styles.productThumbsGallery}>
      <div className={styles.productBoxTop + " " + "product-box-top-swiper-box"}>
        <Swiper
          spaceBetween={10}
          thumbs={{ swiper: thumbsSwiper && !thumbsSwiper.destroyed ? thumbsSwiper : null }}
          modules={[FreeMode, Thumbs]}
          className="mySwiper2"
        >
          {images.map((image) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={image.id}>
              <ReactImageMagnify
                {...{
                  smallImage: {
                    isFluidWidth: true,
                    src: image.url,
                    sizes: "(min-width: 800px) 33.5vw, (min-width: 415px) 50vw, 100vw",
                  },
                  largeImage: {
                    alt: "",
                    src: image.url,
                    width: 1200,
                    height: 1800,
                    style: "z-index: 100"
                  },
                  enlargedImageContainerStyle: {
                    backGroundColor: "black",
                    zIndex: "100"
                  },
                  isHintEnabled: true,
                }}
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </div>

      <div className={styles.productBoxBottom + " " + "product-box-bottom-swiper-box"}>
        <Swiper
          onSwiper={setThumbsSwiper}
          spaceBetween={10}
          slidesPerView={4}
          freeMode={true}
          watchSlidesProgress={true}
          modules={[FreeMode, Thumbs]}
          className="mySwiper"
        >
          {images.map((thumbnail) => (
            <SwiperSlide key={thumbnail.id}>
              <div className={styles.tgBottomBoxImg}>
                <Image
                  src={thumbnail.url}
                  loader={defaultImageLoader}
                  alt={"Loading"}
                  layout="intrinsic"
                  width={850}
                  height={850}
                />
              </div>
            </SwiperSlide>
          ))}
        </Swiper>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductThumbsGallery;


I tried using the example but the example is a bit hard to understand

I faced a similar issue. in my case, this was because I was using Tailwind CSS and it was overwriting some CSS property. To resolve the problem, I added this MagnifyImgContainer class to the container and added the CSS code below to the index.css file
/* unset css for the product image zoom in product slider */

.MagnifyImgContainer img {
  all: unset;
}


Note: In your case, this CSS code may not be the exact solution, inspect your element and do the same for all elements that need to be handled
